# Anyone care to share templated comments?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I use [the AutoReviewComment user script](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/20588) so that it actually pops up for me in the comment box and allows me to choose what to say to users. [I recently shared all of my templated comments for import into this tool on BH.SE.](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/882/423) Anyone else use these *on this site* and care to share? Or even if you keep them in a text file or whatnot, care to share?

Comment: How is it I have not seen that user script yet?!

Comment: David Stratton, I'm waiting for you to post.... :P

Answer (score 10):

These are @David Stratton's comments (some of them slightly modified) as AutoComment. I don't use Chrome, so this is untested; I just needed an excuse to take a break.

There's some repetition here so you may want to just take what you want rather than copy-paste the entire thing.

```
###[Q]New user - Welcome (Good supported answer reference)
Welcome to the site! What follows is just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first): As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [the help page](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites), and [What makes a good supported answer?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

###[A]New user - Welcome 2 (Good supported answer reference)
Welcome to the site! This doesn't really have much to do with the quality of your answer, but I find that sharing the following tends to help new visitors avoid mistaking the purpose of this site. I do hope to see more from you! When you get a chance, please see [How we are different than other sites?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

###[Q]New user - Unclear what s/he is asking
Welcome to the site!  It's very difficult to see what you're asking here, and I'm wondering if you maybe need just a little guidance on how to use this site; It's a bit different than discussion forums you may be familiar with. As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)

###[A]New user - Good quality answer
Welcome to the site! What follows next has ***nothing*** to do with the quality of your answer (which is good); it's just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first). As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [the help page](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites). I hope to see you around!

###New user - Welcome (How are we different)
Welcome to the site! This next has nothing to do with the quality of your post, it's just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [the help page](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)

###[A]New user - How we're different & good supported answer
Welcome to the site. As you're a new visitor, I'd like to recommend the following posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help), [How we are different than other sites?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

###[A]New user - Not an answer (how we're different)
Welcome to the site. As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) Also, this doesn't really answer the question. It looks like it should be a comment on another post, but you haven't yet earned enough reputation to leave comments (Again, see the help page). Hopefully, soon!

###[A]New user - Not an answer (help center)
This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

###[A]New user - Not an answer (help center & how we're different)
Welcome to the site. It seems you've mistaken the purpose of this site. I hope you choose to participate further, but before you do, please see [How we're different than other sites?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [the help page](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help).  Also, this does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

###New user - criticism follow-up
By the way, welcome to the site. Don't take the previous comments as discouragement. It can be tough for new visitors to "get" what this site is about. (It's not what you'd think.) As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)

###[Q]New user: Pastoral advice
Hi and welcome to our community. To clarify a common misconception about this site, we're a fairly academic question and answer site run by a secular company. We have numerous members who are Christians, but because of the nature of this site, we don't answer "advice" questions. It's not that we don't want to help, but on the contrary, we don't feel that it's in anyone's best interest to try to do so on this site.  For more info, please see this post: [Pastoral Advice Questions](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255/pastoral-advice-questions)

###[A]New user - truth argument
Welcome to the site, but I need to point out that "who is right and who is wrong" is off-topic here.  It's not constructive, leads to debate that not welcome on the main site.  See: the [help page](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help), [How we are different than other sites?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

###New user - truth argument 2
Welcome to the site, but I need to point out that "who is right and who is wrong" is off-topic here.  See: the [help page](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help), [How we are different than other sites?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)

###New user misunderstands the site purpose and scope
Welcome to the site. However, it seems you've mistaken the purpose of this site. I hope you choose to participate further, but before you do, you should read [How we are different than other sites?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and then [the help page](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [What makes a good supported answer?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer).

###[Q]New user - Pastoral advice
Hi and welcome to our community; we're a fairly academic question and answer site run by a secular company. We're not a place you should be coming for spiritual advice. We have numerous individual members who are Christians (most of us are), but because of the venue and the nature of this site, we don't answer questions like this (mostly because we don't trust ourselves). With questions like yours we want you to go talk to someone in real life, such as your pastor or priest, a trusted friend, or someone in your church that you trust. I can tell you that we'll pray for you.

###[Q]Off-topic: Pastoral advice
We'd love to help, but total strangers on the Internet are probably not your best bet for getting sound advice. This site is just not meant for that type of support, either.  See [What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt)

###[Q]Off-topic: Pastoral advice follow-up
It's not that we don't want to help, but on the contrary, we don't feel that it's in anyone's best interest to try to do so on this site. For more info, please see this post: [Pastoral Advice Questions](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255/pastoral-advice-questions)

###[A]Request for references
This answer would be a lot better if you could add references showing that this is a common understanding, and who teaches/believes it. Remember that "I believe it means..." isn't an acceptable answer, since this site isn't about personal interpretation.  See [How we are different than other sites?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

###[A]Answer needs references
I'm not arguing the validity of what you say, but this would be a much better answer if you had supporting references. As it is, it reads like a personal interpretation rather than an established teaching. See [What makes a good supported answer?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

###[A]Link-only answer
While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. See [the help topic on why some answers are deleted](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) for more.

###[Q]Question is off-topic
General philosophical or sociological questions are off-topic unless clearly asking for a doctrinal answer.See: [On-topic and constructive examples](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/779/on-topic-and-constructive-examples).

###[A]Help center reference
What you say is good, and I happen to agree, bit it doesn't fit with the purpose of this site. This isn't a discussion forum, it's a Q&A site with a very specific purpose and set of guidelines.  Please see the links above and [the help page](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help)
```

His link-only references:

[the help page](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help)
[we're not here to convince you.](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/how-should-we-address-convince-me-questions)
[What makes a good focused question?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/690/what-makes-a-good-focused-question)
[How can I write my answers objectively and in compliance with the site purpose?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/how-can-i-write-my-answers-objectively-and-in-compliance-with-the-site-purpose)
[How we are different than other sites?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)
[What makes a good supported answer?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)
[What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt)
[Tips for editing a question to make it suitable for re-opening](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/tips-for-editing-a-question-to-make-it-suitable-for-re-opening)
[What to do with “Is x a sin” questions?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1486/what-to-do-with-is-x-a-sin-questions)
it is an [is x a sin question](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1486/what-to-do-with-is-x-a-sin-questions), and is, therefore primarily opinion-based.
[But can't I just say one thing?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1588/but-cant-i-just-say-one-thing)
[Is it valid to ask if “Christianity” teaches anything?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2237/is-it-valid-to-ask-if-christianity-teaches-anything)
[Tips for editing a question to make it suitable for re-opening](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/tips-for-editing-a-question-to-make-it-suitable-for-re-opening)
[Another reason this is not a Christian site](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1457/another-reason-this-is-not-a-christian-site)

Comment: Excellent Ryan! I think it would have been acceptable to edit David's original post instead of repost.

Comment: Nice!  Thank you!

Comment: @fredsbend I can't edit other people's meta posts - does that come with rep?

Comment: @Ryan My mistake, I forgot that there is no edit review on meta, which seems a bit odd. So yes, you need more rep. I think 3k.

Comment: I have been working with the author of the userscript to add per-site default comments to that script and am working on adding data sets. If you install the userscript [from this devel branch](https://raw.github.com/alerque/SE-AutoReviewComments/auto_site_remotes/dist/autoreviewcomments.user.js) and use 'auto » remote » load now' it will now load this comment set as the default for CSE. We are working on cleaning this up for release. Catch us [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13278/autoreviewcomment-script-devel) if you have more ideas!

Answer (score 6):

I've got a few and I keep adding because the templates always seem to me modified to suit the question at hand.  Here's my current list.  The top few are just links to posts I refer to on a regular basis, and then they get into the same stuff I repeat over and over again.

```
[the help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help)

[we're not here to convince you.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/how-should-we-address-convince-me-questions)

[What makes a good focused question?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/690/what-makes-a-good-focused-question)

General philosophical or sociological questions are off-topic unless clearly asking for a doctrinal answer.See: [On-topic and constructive examples](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/779/on-topic-and-constructive-examples).


[How can I write my answers objectively and in compliance with the site purpose?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/how-can-i-write-my-answers-objectively-and-in-compliance-with-the-site-purpose)

[How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)


[What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

 [What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt)


[Tips for editing a question to make it suitable for re-opening](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/tips-for-editing-a-question-to-make-it-suitable-for-re-opening)


[What to do with “Is x a sin” questions?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1486/what-to-do-with-is-x-a-sin-questions)

it is an [is x a sin question](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1486/what-to-do-with-is-x-a-sin-questions), and is, therefore primarily opinion-based.


[But can't I just say one thing?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1588/but-cant-i-just-say-one-thing)



[Is it valid to ask if “Christianity” teaches anything?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2237/is-it-valid-to-ask-if-christianity-teaches-anything)

Welcome to the site.  However, it seems you've mistaken the purpose of this site.  I hope you choose to participate further, but before you do, you should read [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and then [the help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

Welcome to the site!  It's very difficult to see what you're asking here, and I'm wondering if you maybe need just a little guidance on how to use this site?  It's a bit different than discussion forums you may be familiar with.  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)


Welcome to the site!  This next is just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [the help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites), and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

Welcome to the site!  This doesn't really have much to do with your answer, but I find that sharing the following tends to help new visitors avoid mistaking the purpose of this site. I do hope to see more from you!  When you get a chance, please see [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

Welcome to the site!  This next has nothing to do with the quality of your answer, it's just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [the help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)


Welcome to the site!  This next has ***nothing*** to do with the quality of your answer, it's just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [the help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)


Welcome to the site!  This next has nothing to do with the quality of your question, it's just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)


  Welcome to the site!  This next is just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)


Welcome to the site!  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)

Welcome to the site. As you're a new visitor, I'd like to recommend the following posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help), [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)


This answer would be a lot better if you could add references showing that this is a common understanding, and who teaches/believes it. Remember that "I believe it means..." isn't an acceptable answer, since this site isn't about personal interpretation.  See [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)


This answer would be a lot better if you could add references showing that this is a common understanding, and who teaches/believes it. On this site, we're not looking for personal interpretation, but rather focusing on what various Christian groups teach.  See [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

What you say is good, and I happen to agree, bit it doesn't fit with the purpose of this site. This isn't a discussion forum, it's a Q&A site with a very specific purpose and set of guidelines.  Please see the links above and [the help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help)

Welcome to the site. As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) Also, this doesn't really answer the question. It looks like it should be a comment on another post, but you haven't yet earned enough to leave comments.  (Again, see the help page.)  Hopefully, soon!


This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post
- you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Welcome to the site.  It seems you've mistaken the purpose of this site.  I hope you choose to participate further, but before you do, please see [How we're different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [the help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help).  Also, this does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.  See [the help topic on why some answers are deleted](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) for more.


[Tips for editing a question to make it suitable for re-opening](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/tips-for-editing-a-question-to-make-it-suitable-for-re-opening)

We'd love to help, but total strangers on the Internet are probably not your best bet for getting sound advice.  This site is just not meant for that type of support, either.  See [What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt)


[Another reason this is not a Christian site](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1457/another-reason-this-is-not-a-christian-site)


I'm not arguing the validity of what you say, but this would be a much better answer if you had supporting references. As it is, it reads like a personal interpretation rather than an established teaching.  See [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)



By the way, welcome to the site.  Don't take the previous comments as discouragement. It can be tough for new visitors to "get" what this site is about.  (It's not what you'd think.) As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)



Hi and welcome to our community, just a bit about us, we're a fairly academic question and answer site run by a secular company. We're not somewhere you should be coming for spiritual advice. We have numerous individual members who are Christians (most of us are), but because of the venue and the nature of this site, we don't answer questions like this. Mostly because we don't trust ourselves. With questions like yours we want you to go talk to someone in real life. Your pastor or priest, a trusted friend, or someone in your church that you trust. I can tell you that we'll pray for you.

It's not that we don't want to help, but on the contrary, we don't feel that it's in anyone's best interest to try to do so on this site. For more info, please see this post:  [Pastoral Advice Questions](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/255/pastoral-advice-questions)




Hi and welcome to our community. To clarify a common misconception about this site, we're a fairly academic question and answer site run by a secular company.  We have numerous members who are Christians, but because of the nature of this site, we don't answer "advice" questions. It's not that we don't want to help, but on the contrary, we don't feel that it's in anyone's best interest to try to do so on this site.  For more info, please see this post:  [Pastoral Advice Questions](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/255/pastoral-advice-questions)


Welcome to the site, but I need to point out that "who is right and who is wrong" is off-topic here.  It's not constructive, leads to debate that not welcome on the main site.  See: the [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help), [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)


Welcome to the site, but I need to point out that "who is right and who is wrong" is off-topic here.  See: the [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help), [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)
```

Comment: Looks like you keep these on a separate scratch pad. Iy anybody feels like setting these up for the [auto-comment userscript](http://stackapps.com/q/2116/20588) that would be awesome(er).

Comment: Yeah, mine are all in OneNote.  I should get the auto-comment, so if anyone does the work of converting mine, I'd be grateful as well.

Comment: I also notice that you have the actual title of the questions in the links. There is a userscript that converts the plain old link to the title. That would save you some characters.

Comment: Thanks so much!!!

Comment: If you didn't want to install the Auto-comment, you *could* always use: http://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: David Stratton is the Jon Skeet of commenting on C.SE

Answer (score 4):

I have recently put something together. I will likely add more later (still working on the best wording for the first one). I will add them in order as a comment under this post (the first is actually at the bottom), so you can vote on them individually. I added pseudo headings, so they are easier to find.

Here's snapshots of the plugin. Hidden description first:

[image]

Now here's expanded description:

[image]
[image]

Here's the actual text of the comments (this will be current as I edit them):

> #### ===ANSWER COMMENTS===
>
> #### Answer is all opinion
>
> Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. This answer needs more support. It needs sources and
> citations, if necessary, to support what you are saying. Otherwise, it
> just looks like your opinion. Please add more to it to make a truly
> academic answer. Thank you.
>
> #### Add more to this answer.
>
> Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. The community here prefers longer answers.
> Please see [Guidelines for writing effective
> answers](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1920/guidelines-for-writing-effective-answers)
> and [What is a well-sourced, dispassionate
> answer?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/what-is-a-well-sourced-dispassionate-answer)
> After that, please edit this post to make it better. I hope to see you
> post again soon.
>
> #### Answer is only a comment
>
> This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post
> comments](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment). You should delete this
> because it is not answer to the question. Please also see [What this
> site is
> about](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt/)
> and [How this site is
> different.](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809)
> I hope to see you post again soon.
>
> #### Answer is another question
>
> This is really another question, not an answer. You can ask another question by clicking on the [Ask
> Question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) link at the top of the page.
> You should delete this because it is not answer. Please also see [What
> this site is
> about](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt/)
> and [How this site is
> different.](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809)
> I hope to see you post again soon.
>
> #### ===QUESTION COMMENTS===
>
> #### Question might be better on Hermenutics
>
> This might be better on the [hermeneutics site](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com). Examining
> translations and looking at exact word meanings is what they do there.
> You can delete this and post it there, or flag it and ask the
> moderators to migrate it as is.
>
> #### Old question is off-topic and needs an edit or close vote.
>
> Please bring this old question into current site guidelines. Thanks. Resource
> for your convenience: [Question types that the community finds
> acceptable.](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-or-template-questions-that-the-community-generally-finds-ac)
>
> #### Types of questions
>
> Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. This question is off-topic and does not fit into one of
> the [question types that the community finds
> acceptable.](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-or-template-questions-that-the-community-generally-finds-ac)
> If possible, edit this question so that it better fits into one of
> those question types.
>
> #### ===MISC. COMMENTS===
>
> #### Question has changed
>
> The question has significantly changed. You might want to edit your answer.
>
> #### Fix the grammar and spelling
>
> Please edit this post so that it has proper grammar and no spelling errors. The site strives for an
> academic tone, which includes academic quality grammar and spelling.
> Thank you.
>
> #### Frustrated user
>
> I know getting the hang of this site can be difficult. I had a good deal of frustration at first too. I have
> written a post to help you: [Newcomers: Be patient. You will get there
> if you follow our direction. Keep
> trying.](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1927/newcomers-be-patient-you-will-get-there-if-you-follow-our-direction-keep-tryi)
> Many of the regular users are often available in
> [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1167/the-upper-room). They
> would likely be willing to help you.

SOURCE

```
###===ANSWER COMMENTS===
asdf

###Answer is all opinion
Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. This answer needs more support. It needs sources and citations, if necessary, to support what you are saying. Otherwise, it just looks like your opinion. Please add more to it to make a truly academic answer. Thank you.

###Add more to this answer.
Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. The community here prefers longer answers. Please see [Guidelines for writing effective answers](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1920/guidelines-for-writing-effective-answers) and [What is a well-sourced, dispassionate answer?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/what-is-a-well-sourced-dispassionate-answer) After that, please edit this post to make it better. I hope to see you post again soon.

###Answer is only a comment
This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://$SITEURL$/privileges/comment). You should delete this because it is not answer to the question. Please also see [What this site is about](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt/) and [How this site is different.](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809) I hope to see you post again soon.

###Answer is another question
This is really another question, not an answer. You can ask another question by clicking on the [Ask Question](http://$SITEURL$/questions/ask) link at the top of the page. You should delete this because it is not answer. Please also see [What this site is about](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt/) and [How this site is different.](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809) I hope to see you post again soon.

###===QUESTION COMMENTS===
asdf

###Question might be better on Hermenutics
This might be better on the [hermeneutics site](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com). Examining translations and looking at exact word meanings is what they do there. You can delete this and post it there, or flag it and ask the moderators to migrate it as is.

###Old question is off-topic and needs an edit or close vote.
Please bring this old question into current site guidelines. Thanks. Resource for your convenience: [Question types that the community finds acceptable.](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-or-template-questions-that-the-community-generally-finds-ac)

###Types of questions
Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. This question is off-topic and does not fit into one of the [question types that the community finds acceptable.](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-or-template-questions-that-the-community-generally-finds-ac) If possible, edit this question so that it better fits into one of those question types.

###===MISC. COMMENTS===
asdf

###Question has changed
The question has significantly changed. You might want to edit your answer.

###Fix the grammar and spelling
Please edit this post so that it has proper grammar and no spelling errors. The site strives for an academic tone, which includes academic quality grammar and spelling. Thank you.

###Frustrated user
I know getting the hang of this site can be difficult. I had a good deal of frustration at first too. I have written a post to help you: [Newcomers: Be patient. You will get there if you follow our direction. Keep trying.](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1927/newcomers-be-patient-you-will-get-there-if-you-follow-our-direction-keep-tryi) Many of the regular users are often available in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1167/the-upper-room). They would likely be willing to help you.
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. The community here prefers longer answers. Please see [Guidelines for writing effective answers](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1920/guidelines-for-writing-effective-answers) and [What is a well-sourced, dispassionate answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/886/what-is-a-well-sourced-dispassionate-answer) After that, please edit this post to make it better. I hope to see you post again soon.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment). You should delete this because it is not answer to the question. Please also see [What this site is about](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt/) and [How this site is different.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809) I hope to see you post again soon.

Comment: This is really another question, not an answer. You can ask another question by clicking on the [Ask Question](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) link at the top of the page. You should delete this because it is not answer. Please also see [What this site is about](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt/) and [How this site is different.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809) I hope to see you post again soon.

Comment: This might be better on the [hermeneutics site](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com). Examining translations and looking at exact word meanings is what they do there. You can delete this and post it there, or flag it and ask the moderators to migrate it as is.

Comment: Please bring this old question into current site guidelines. Thanks. Resource for your convenience: [Question types that the community finds acceptable.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-or-template-questions-that-the-community-generally-finds-ac)

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. This question is off-topic and does not fit into one of the [question types that the community finds acceptable.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-or-template-questions-that-the-community-generally-finds-ac) If possible, edit this question so that it better fits into one of those question types.

Comment: The question has significantly changed. You might want to edit your answer.

Comment: Please edit this post so that it has proper grammar and no spelling errors. The site strives for an academic tone, which includes academic quality grammar and spelling. Thank you.

Comment: I know getting the hang of this site can be difficult. I had a good deal of frustration at first too. I have written a post to help you: [Newcomers: Be patient. You will get there if you follow our direction. Keep trying.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1927/newcomers-be-patient-you-will-get-there-if-you-follow-our-direction-keep-tryi) Many of the regular users are often available in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1167/the-upper-room). They would likely be willing to help you.

Comment: **ANSWER IS ALL OPINION:** Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. This answer needs more support. It needs sources and citations, if necessary, to support what you are saying. Otherwise, it just looks like your opinion. Please add more to it to make a truly academic answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my default comment:

> Welcome to the site! You have an interesting answer. Please consider adding references to your answer to better solidify it as a good answer. Please consider reading [What makes a good supported answer?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/692/) and / or [How we are different than other sites?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808/)

```
Welcome to the site! You have an interesting answer. Please consider adding references to your answer to better solidify it as a good answer. Please consider reading [What makes a good supported answer?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/692/) and / or [How we are different than other sites?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808/)
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

I want to share mine! I think this is a good place to put it. It's on-topic, so I can find it for future use.

```
The answer can be greatly improved if you can list the sources with which you used to derive your answer or conclusion. If you happen to speak for your own denomination, please list your denomination here. Thank you for your consideration.
```

Comment: I like it, except I would just say "Thank you" instead of "Thank you for your cooperation". Some people are overly sensitive to that and might feel like they are being told what to do.